# Django jquery dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html.dropdownlistfor

I try to do a test with a dropdown list {{ form.droits_acces }} (all, group, private) from a script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('body').data('form.droits_acces', {{ form.droits_acces }});

var op_id = $('body').data('form.droits_acces');

$('.group').hide();

$('#selectMe').change(function () {
$('.group').show(); // I want to show group if it is selected

}); 

});
```

html

```
<div id="selectMe"   >
{{ form.droits_acces }}
</div>
<div class="group" >
{{ form.groupe }}
</div>
```

how to do this test in javascript  ?

```
if($(#selecMe.val()== "group") {
$('.group').show();

}
```

if I put a message alert(op_id), I display :

```
<select name="droits_acces" id="id_droits_acces">
 <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="lecture">all</option>
 <option value="groupe">group</option>
 <option value="private">private data</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($('#selecMe').val() == "group") {
$('.group').show();
}
```

Comment: if I put gg = $('#selecMe').val(); alert(gg); I display 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
if($('#selecMe').val()== "groupe") {
// - ^        ^^ add this
    $('.group').show();
}
```

instead of:

```
if($(#selecMe.val()== "group") {
    $('.group').show();
}
```

You need to wrap the selector inside quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "` as well as the value name is `groupe` not `group`

Comment: if I put gg = $('#selecMe').val(); alert(gg); I display 'undefined'

Comment: Your `select ` id is `id_droits_acces` not `selectMe`?

Comment: I found the solution:                                              var value=$('option:selected', $(this)).text();                  if(value == "group") {                                        $('.group').show();}

Comment: So you're getting the text of your `option`, not value of it already.

Comment: If you want to compare with the value you need to use `if($('#selecMe').val() == "groupe")`. Notice the difference between `group` and `groupe`

Comment: I just wanted to get the text

Comment: explain why the message is in this case : 'undefined'

Comment: Because the value of `group` is `groupe`, not `group`. Please check your HTML markup. That's why you getting `undefined`